# Tribulation and Jubilation

Tags: knowledge, visual

Happy weekend puzzlers

As ever from me a Venn-based game.  The three circles represent as yet unknown categories - their intersection forms seven curved regions - and your job is to place the right tiles in the right regions.
In today's puzzle you are given nine tiles - and also told how many tiles should be placed in each region - this is the number in the [] brackets.  So which tiles go where and why?

[image: Venn Diagram with 9 words: Bundy, Wittstock, Royle, Spencer, Manson, Josef K, Brady, Ferguson, Simpson]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Venn diagram should resolve as follows:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

The three categories are:

**Top left:**

> People who have **famously been on trial** (link to title: 'trials and tribulations')
>
>  [Ian Brady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moors_murders#Ian_Brady), [Ted Bundy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Bundy), [Charles Manson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Manson), [OJ Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._J._Simpson), and - in fiction - [Josef K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial)
>
>  ('Famously' is key here - I'm pretty sure that if you dig deep enough you could find trials featuring people with the other surnames here, but none quite as high-profile as these...)

**Top right:**

> **Television sitcom families**
>
>  Brady ([*The Brady Bunch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brady_Bunch))
>  Bundy ([*Married... with Children*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married..._with_Children))
>  Royle ([*The Royle Family*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Royle_Family))
>  Simpson ([*The Simpsons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Simpsons))
>  Spencer ([*Some Mothers Do 'Ave 'Em*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Some_Mothers_Do_%27Ave_%27Em))

**Bottom:**

> People who have **married into a royal family** (link to title: 'jubilation' → 'jubilee' and a sense of celebration)
>
>  The British royal family:
>  [Wallis Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_Simpson), married then-Prince Edward (later King Edward VIII) in 1937;
>  [Diana Spencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana,_Princess_of_Wales), married Prince Charles in 1981;
>  [Sarah Ferguson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah,_Duchess_of_York), married Prince Andrew in 1986.
>
>  And one from Monaco:
>  [Charlene Wittstock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlene,_Princess_of_Monaco), married Prince Albert II of Monaco in 2011.

The central shared word is thus:

> Simpson

Comment: As ever - chapeau! Always tricky when things are “famous” rather than definitive!!!